# вывод таблиц из базы SHOW TABLES msqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Столкнулся вот с такой проблемкой. Я хочу вывести таблицы из базы данных, вот таки образом:

```
$result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES");
 while ( $row = $result->fetch_row()){
  $table = $row[0];
  echo $table;
$result1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
  if($result1) {
   echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table">';
$column = $conn->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
  echo '<tr>';
while($row3 = $column->fetch_row()) {
  echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';
}
  echo '</tr>';
while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row()) {
  echo '<tr>';
foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
  echo '<td width="15%">',$value,'</td>';
}
  echo '</tr>';
}
  echo '</table><br/>';
}
}
```

выводи все отлично, но есть моменты, которые я хотел бы решить:
 1. Как запретить вывод определенных таблиц
 2. Как вывести только нужные колонки или ограничить их число , а если в таблице нет колонки, вместо нее вывести другую.
**Например:** *В таблице Новости, есть колонки текст, а в таблице Юзеры нет, вместо колонки **Текст**, вывести **Логин***.

Заранее спасибо.
П.С.: Только не бейте =)

Comment: `if ($table не надо выводить)`; `select field1, field2, field3 from`

Comment: не совсем понимаю, как я это смогу использовать в случае, с полями в таблицах?

Comment: Создайте массив `имя таблицы => поля для выбора` и подставляйте в запрос.